# MATE notification area glitches when there's not an internet connection

Tags: linux, networking, mate, parrot-os

The notification area just looks keeps glitching until it's connected to internet

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RljC.gif)

Comment: Have you tried process-of-elimination troubleshooting by turning off things that appear there, until you see the glitches stop, to help you determine which item (or combination of items) is glitching out?

Comment: Thanks @Spiff, that actually seems to help , when I hibernated the device and restarted it it stopped, I'll debug it the next time

Comment: It's probable related with the microphone service or the screen recorder